# Cannot `stat` inside /dev/fd on MacOS

Tags: macos

I can `ls` the contents of `/dev/fd`...

```
$ ls -Al /dev/fd
total 0
crw--w----   1 andy  tty     16,   1 Jan 25 14:17 0
crw--w----   1 andy  tty     16,   1 Jan 25 14:17 1
crw--w----   1 andy  tty     16,   1 Jan 25 14:17 2
drw-r--r--  19 andy  staff       608 Jan 25 00:43 3/
dr--r--r--   1 root  wheel         0 Jan 23 20:42 4/
```

But I can't inspect the dirs `3/` or `4/` with `stat`.

```
$ stat /dev/fd/4
stat: /dev/fd/4: stat: Bad file descriptor
```

*Why?* I'm trying to re-implement the `ls` command for my own learning purposes and this is really tripping me up!

I'm on MacOS High Sierra 10.13.2

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48522735/307692) on SO, and read [liamseanbrady's blog post](https://liamseanbrady.wordpress.com/2016/03/28/the-great-file-descriptor-mystery/) on the subject.